# Adding one more g500 in uwsim?

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to add 1 or more robots in uwsim ? Can we simply do it by editing cirs.xml ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189675/adding-one-more-g500-in-uwsim?/) by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can take the scene 'shipwreck.xml' scene as an example:
rosrun uwsim uwsim --configfile shipwreck.xml

---

Originally posted by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) with karma: 291 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-08-12**:
thanks  a lot .